# How to give priority to angular routing instead of node routing while using html5Mode(true) in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url-routing, angular-routing, html5mode

I want to route my application according to angular routes in `html5mode(true)`. Here is my angular code snippet.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <base href="/">
        <!-- Import Angular -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Import Angular Route -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Import Local JS Files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/userController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view ng-app="myApp"></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['appRoute'])
```

**app.routes.js**

```
angular.module('appRoute', ['ngRoute', 'userController'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true
    });
    $routeProvider
    .when('/user', {
        templateUrl: 'app/user.html',
        controller: 'UserController',
        controllerAs: 'user'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/user'
    });
});
```

**userController.js**

```
angular.module('userController', [])
.controller('UserController', function() {

});
```

But when I hit the url i.e. http://0.0.0.0:3000 in my browser, it redirects the url to http://0.0.0.0:3000/user which is correct but when I try to reload it tells me `Cannot GET /user` which I guess is a response from Node server. How can I configure my application so that browser uses http://0.0.0.0:3000 or http://0.0.0.0:3000/user.

**Update**: NodeJS server code.

```
// grab all we need
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// setup public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + 'public');

// set up the server
var server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log('Server connected at ' + this.address().address + ':' + this.address().port);
});

// export exposed variable
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: use localhost instead

Comment: same result with localhost

Comment: Update answer and include your NodeJS code. Are you using Express framework?

Comment: @gdyrrahitis added. Yes, Express framework.

Comment: your folder structure? are you placing all the files inside app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a catch-all rule for routing in your server code.

Update code by adding this rule before setting-up your server:

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode. Assuming your index.html is at application root
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

This will catch all the other requests (different from the root) and redirect them back to index.html in order to support the HTML5 mode.

Essentially, your server code should look like this:

```
// grab all we need
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// setup public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + 'public');

/* CATCH-ALL RULE HERE */
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

// set up the server
var server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log('Server connected at ' + this.address().address + ':' + this.address().port);
});

// export exposed variable
module.exports = app;
```